# Error using aapt2 link command with androidx appcompat library

Tags: android, aapt2

I'm attempting to create Java sources for the R class using aapt2, however it results in errors that I'm having trouble working out how to resolve. The library in question is the [androidx appcompat library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat/1.0.2), specifically version 1.0.2.

My steps are:

Extract the .aar to its own folder. In this case: `C:\Temp\appcompat-1.0.2`

Execute aapt2 compile:

```
"C:\Android\SDK\build-tools\31.0.0\aapt2.exe" compile --dir "C:\Temp\appcompat-1.0.2\res" -o "C:\Temp\compiled_res.flata"
```

Execute aapt2 link:

```
"C:\Android\SDK\build-tools\31.0.0\aapt2.exe" link --auto-add-overlay -I "C:\Android\SDK\platforms\android-31\android.jar" --manifest "C:\Temp\appcompat-1.0.2\AndroidManifest.xml" -R "C:\Temp\compiled_res.flata" -o "C:\Temp\linked_res.ap_" --java "C:\Temp\src"
```

This results in:

```
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml:20: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml:20: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_tint_default.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_tint_edittext.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_tint_spinner.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:20: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
C:\Temp\appcompat.1.0.2\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:21: error: attribute alpha (aka androidx.appcompat:alpha) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

I assume that there's something I'm missing?